# Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.10.42 Suspend can't wake

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

Here are the outputs:

`$uname -r`

`$4.10.42-generic`

---

`nvcc --version`

`nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61`

---

`nvidia-smi`

[Output of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d80C1.png)

---

Please let me know if you need any other information.

The issue is:

When I try to wake it from suspend, it will try to wake. But after a while the computer just dies (with no monitor output). Clicking on the start button on the case doesn't fix it either; The same problem: tries to start, but it dies.

Stuff I tried:

I tried upgrading to kernel 4.13 and 4.14; but none of them work well with nvidia driver 387. I have a feeling that its a driver issue;

The only way to fix it for now is to cut off the power completely to the motherboard. And then reconnect the power and restart.

Please let me know what you think the problem is.

Comment: Does Ubuntu 16.04 use that kernel officially?

Comment: Try ping the computer, or connect to it via SSH after it "dies", does it work?

Comment: Yes - ubuntu uses that kernel officially.

Comment: No, it doesn't work unfortunately pinging using ssh after it dies. (I do have ssh installed and its working normally.)

Comment: To be sure it is really a video driver issue, try use another nvidia drive (i.e. The open source one), be sure to remove the old one before continue, and see if the issue still exists.